# Write dynamic reference in Google Sheets (like `#` in Excel)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

In the following worksheet in Excel, the formula of D3 is `=UNIQUE(B3:D9)`, the formula of F3 is `=SORT(D3#)`, where `D3#` refers to the dynamic result of D3.

[image]

In Google Sheets, we could well write `=UNIQUE(D3:D9)`, and the function `SORT` exists. But `#` does not work. Does anyone know how to write such a dynamic reference?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data is implicitly dynamic at Google. Write:

`=SORT(D:D)`

instead.

Comment: It will also include D1, D2 but `D3:D` will start from D3 then last cell of D column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=SORT(D3:D)` here `D3:D` will refer cells from D3 to last last of column D. For `UNIQUE()` you can try

```
=UNIQUE(D3:D)
```